# Different results of np.var() in python vs DolphinDB

Tags: python, variance, dolphindb

Python:

```
np.var([1,6,2]) = 4.666666666666667
```

DolphinDB:

```
var(1 6 2) = 7
```

Why are the variance results returned are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
np.var([1,6,2] ,ddof=1)
```

> ddofint, optional
> “Delta Degrees of Freedom”: the divisor used in the calculation is N - ddof, where N represents the number of elements. By default ddof
> is zero

[numpy.var in numpy document](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.var.html)

edit: (description added from [Serge Ballesta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3545273/serge-ballesta)'s replay. thanks)

The underlying rationale is that you could compute a variance from a whole population (meaning that the average is known exactly) or from only a sample (meaning only an approximation of the average). Probability mathematics then show that you have to use a delta degrees of freedom of 1 for a sample (aka variance n-1) while you use ddof=0 for a whole set (aka variance n).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The underlying rationale is that you could compute a variance from a whole population (meaning that the average is known exactly) or from only a sample (meaning only an approximation of the average). Probability mathematics then show that you have to use a *delta degrees of freedom* of 1 for a sample (aka variance n-1) while you use ddof=0 for a whole set (aka variance n). If you added that to your answer it would be much better, and I could upvote it

Answer (score 0):

`np.var()` calculates the population variance but `var()` calculates the sample variance.

The denominator will be off by 1.

If you are using DolphinDB, try varp() to get the same result.

```
varp(1 6 2) = 4.666666666666667
```